# pyspark issue with round function

Tags: python, pyspark, rounding, rdd

I am using zeppelin pyspark and trying to round a column value of an RDD (converted from Dataframe) but getting error.

```
    %pyspark
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    orderfinal = orderjoin.rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[1], x[2]), (x[4], x[5]))). \
        combineByKey(lambda value: (value[0], value[1]),
                        lambda x, value: (x[0] + value[0], x[1] + value[1]),
                        lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1])). \
        map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1].strftime("%Y-%B-%d"), x[1][0], float(x[1][1])))
    for i in (orderfinal.take(5)): print i
```

```
(u'Shipped', '2003-November-06', 977, 99916.59000000001)
(u'Shipped', '2004-February-18', 167, 16901.38)
(u'Shipped', '2003-April-11', 27, 1627.56)
(u'Shipped', '2004-April-02', 390, 29284.420000000002)
(u'Shipped', '2004-October-06', 70, 3474.66)
```

Now I tried to round the last column from the RDD

```
    %pyspark
    orderfinal.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], round(x[3], 2))).take(5)
```

```
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 567, in round
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.round(_to_java_column(col), scale))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

I then tried to run the simple python round function but still getting error.

```
    %pyspark
    print(round(3424.34242342,2))
```

```
Fail to execute line 1: print(round(3424.34242342,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6587764996600827880.py", line 380, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 567, in round
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.round(_to_java_column(col), scale))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 54, in _to_java_column
    "function.".format(col, type(col)))
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 3424.34242342 of type <type 'float'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

I tried to do round in dataframe and its working fine but not in the RDD. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given your RDD snippet and this specific `_jvm` error, this is most likely a context or namespace issue. I'd recommend creating a fresh environment and checking if this resolves itself.

Comment: In particular, I wonder if you may have a collision with the built-in round function and PySpark's round function, perhaps due to importing an entire namespace.

Comment: As Nick Becker said, since you have import ed pyspark.sql.functions. Round function of dataframes has overriden the python round function, hence "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'" error is occurring. Restart your notebook and run it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the documentation for [pyspark.sql.functions.round()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.round)
, it takes an input of a `col` object. Hence it will not work for a `float` value such as `3424.342434`.

However with `RDD`'s or singular variables you should use the inbuilt `round()` or `np.round()` function.

```
%pyspark
print(round(3424.34242342,2))
```

^ I think the inbuilt `round` function is overriden by the `pyspark` function right here.